# First Name and Last Name Single line error during validation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Normal image

[image: 1]

Error image flutter

[image: 2]

Hello everyone, I am trying to keep **First Name** and **Last Name** in a single line during validation. If I don't add text in both so, I am getting it in a single line, but when I don't add text in only one one tag at that time another container is staying up-down. So, can You please suggest, how can I keep these both in a single line and together when one or both container have error.
Thank

Comment: Share your code.

Answer (score 1):

if you wrap your container with `Row` widget, then you can set property to the row

```
Row(
 // to align vertically both children to the top 
 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
 children:[
   Container() // first name
   Container() // last name
 ]),
// others widget
```

Comment: since its `Textfield`  i think you have to wrap the container with `Expanded`  widget. to avoid error for the `Row` widget.

Answer (score 0):

```
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: const [
                Expanded(child: TextField()),
                Expanded(child: TextField()),
              ],
            )
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: @JeremyCaney Thanks. I will take care of these things.